# R googlesheets gs_ls() returns Content Type Error

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am trying our the R googlesheets package and I ran into an issue just trying to pull up the list of sheets.  I ran the authentication process and I don't think its related to authentication issues.

The error seems to be related with out the sheets are set up?

```
library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)


gs_auth(new_user = T)
# This brought up my browser and I authenticated and it seemed to run fine

gs_ls()
Error in stop_for_content_type(req, expected = "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8") : 
  Expected content-type:
application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
Actual content-type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Running R 3.5.0 on Windows 10

Comment: Are they google sheets in the drive, or are they excel files in the drive?

Comment: I think most are either excel files I've uploaded or I copied from Excel and pasted to Google sheets.

Comment: https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/259 This issue has been brought up on the GitHub issues for this package, I would say make sure you have the most recent version of the package and then check locale settings. This is linked as well https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/182